# Angles of which locations of points corresponding to distances intersect each other

Tags: calculus, geometry

*Original problem :*

In the $XY$ plane,Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ two points with coordinates $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. $C_1$ is the locus of points whose sum of distances to $P_1$ and $P_2$ is $4$. 
$C_2$ is the locus of points whose difference of distances to P1 and P2 is $±1$.

With what angle these two places intersecting each other?

> Basics through which I think it helps to solve the original problem:
>   $C_1$ and $C_2$ do they belong to which type of curve? Can we have their equation?

I am tottaly stuck here, I cannot translate the assumptions into clear and distinct ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Sum is easy: take a piece of ribbon, length 4 arbitrary units, and fix its endpoints 2 units apart. Take a pencil and use it to draw a curve while keeping the string taut. That's $C_1$. Recognize that shape?

Difference is harder, but if you recognize $C_1$ then you might start looking at [conic sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) and find the class for $C_2$ there as well.

[image: Figure]